# How to send a message to the client from the backend server use Workerman?

Tags: php, websocket

Please help me figure out the Workerman library I'm using for websockets.

server.php:

```
use Workerman\Worker;
require_once '/usr/local/workerman/vendor/autoload.php';
$ws_worker = new Worker('websocket://1.1.1.1:2346');
$ws_worker->onWorkerStart = function($ws_worker)
{
    $http_worker = new Worker('http://127.0.0.1:2023');
    $http_worker->onMessage = function($http_connection, $request) use ($ws_worker) {
        //this code does not work:
        foreach($ws_worker->connections as $connection) {
            $connection->send($request);
        }
    };
    $http_worker->listen();
};

// this code works correctly:
$ws_worker->onMessage = function ($con, $data) use ($ws_worker) {
    foreach($ws_worker->connections as $connection) {
        $connection->send($data);
    }
};
Worker::runAll();
```

client.html:

```
<input type="number" id="input" onchange="ws.send(value); value='';" autofocus="autofocus">
<br><br>
<div id="div" rows="2"></div>
<script>
  ws = new WebSocket("ws://1.1.1.1:2346");
  const div = document.getElementById('div');
  const input = document.getElementById('input');
  ws.onopen = function() {
    alert("connection success");
      console.log(ws);
    };
  ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    div.innerText += e.data + "\n";
    console.log(e.data + "\n");
  };
</script>
```

The data sent from input in client.html is successfully displayed in DIV on the client.html page.
My problem is sending data from backend PHP script. For this I use the following code:

```
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1:2023';
$data = '12345'; // or '{"data": "12345"}'
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type: application/json")
]);
$curl_result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_export($curl_result); // return true
```

I expect that '12345' should appear in the DIV on the client.html page, but this does not happen. I believe that the event '$http_worker->onMessage' does not work.
What am I doing wrong?